Repair boot Ubuntu on another computer
I have broken the boot of a disk sdd with Ubuntu on a A-computer.
I tried to repair the boot of this disk on a B-computer because I have no USB port sdb on A-computer to use a live USB.
I tried to use boot repair from a live USB on this computer B because B-Computer is completely different to A-Computer (Windows - legacy).
Do you know what I should pay particular attention to? For example, the default UEFI wasn't checked on tab2 and the proposed solution was to install grub MBR on sda as you can see in the boot info. So I don't want to modify the sda partition, only the sdd partitions.



============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdd and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos5)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32784 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

sdd1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdd2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdd5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdd6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (windows):   Windows 10 (boot) on sda1
OS#2 (linux):   Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on mapper/crypt-root
OS#3 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on sda2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GT218 [GeForce G210] from NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, focal, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 6.08   (8.15) from American Megatrends Inc.
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdd : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  usb-disk,   not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdd1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdd5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far
mapper/crypt-root   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot, ntfs
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sdd1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sdd5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
mapper/crypt-root   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sdd1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdd
sdd5    : is---sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdd
mapper/crypt-root   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  fstab-has-goodBOOT, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0f8b607c
     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1  *         2048   1126399   1124352   549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2         1126400 975647940 974521541 464.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3       975648768 976769023   1120256   547M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
Disk sdb: 15 GiB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x4060af9a
     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 31457247 31455200  15G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Disk sdd: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x3fb22b3d
     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sdd1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
sdd2       1052670 500117503 499064834   238G  5 Extended
sdd5       1052672   2549759   1497088   731M 83 Linux
sdd6       2551808 500117503 497565696 237.3G 83 Linux
Disk mapper/luks-36aadf0f-9ed5-4c9a-ab49-82490351ab49: 237.25 GiB, 254736859136 bytes, 497532928 sectors
Disk mapper/crypt-root: 223.18 GiB, 239633170432 bytes, 468033536 sectors
Disk mapper/crypt-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Disk mapper/crypt-swap_2: 4 GiB, 4294967296 bytes, 8388608 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:500GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA Samsung SSD 870:;
1:1049kB:577MB:576MB:ntfs::boot;
2:577MB:500GB:499GB:ntfs::;
3:500GB:500GB:574MB:ntfs::msftres;
sdb:16.1GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Generic Flash Disk:;
1:1049kB:16.1GB:16.1GB:fat32::boot, lba;
sdd:256GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:MTFDHBA2 56TCK-1AS1AA:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32::boot;
2:539MB:256GB:256GB:::;
5:539MB:1305MB:767MB:ext4::;
6:1307MB:256GB:255GB:::;
mapper/crypt-swap_2:4295MB:dm:512:4096:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:4295MB:4295MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
mapper/crypt-root:240GB:dm:512:4096:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:240GB:240GB:ext4::;
mapper/crypt-swap_1:1023MB:dm:512:4096:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:1023MB:1023MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
mapper/luks-36aadf0f-9ed5-4c9a-ab49-82490351ab49:255GB:dm:512:4096:unknown:Linux device-mapper (crypt):;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                                          FSTYPE      UUID                                   PARTUUID                             LABEL              PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                                                      
├─sda1                                        ntfs        3EFA09DDFA099277                       0f8b607c-01                          Réservé au système 
├─sda2                                        ntfs        74720B3B720B019A                       0f8b607c-02                                             
└─sda3                                        ntfs        70AED1B4AED17358                       0f8b607c-03                                             
sdb                                                                                                                                                      
└─sdb1                                        vfat        849E-DC4E                              4060af9a-01                          UBUNTU 20_0        
sdd                                                                                                                                                      
├─sdd1                                        vfat        43E3-C49F                              3fb22b3d-01                                             
├─sdd2                                                                                           3fb22b3d-02                                             
├─sdd5                                        ext4        e754ef8b-0783-4e95-9bbd-26b2fb0b9e25   3fb22b3d-05                                             
└─sdd6                                        crypto_LUKS 36aadf0f-9ed5-4c9a-ab49-82490351ab49   3fb22b3d-06                                             
  └─luks-36aadf0f-9ed5-4c9a-ab49-82490351ab49 LVM2_member t3WzIL-7Lks-x25L-EAFS-FHAi-V0rt-PpOAEm                                                         
    ├─crypt-root                              ext4        eb8d3fc1-635e-4612-93d5-3b551fee8d2c                                                           
    ├─crypt-swap_1                            swap        9d7ef9bf-8a9d-43bd-9de4-3b2adf69f6d2                                                           
    └─crypt-swap_2                            swap        a396daf8-2604-4e5f-957a-1f01a7bbe4b2                                                           

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/crypt-root   106G  47% /media/ubuntu/eb8d3fc1-635e-4612-93d5-3b551fee8d2c
/dev/sda1              518.1M   6% /media/ubuntu/Rxc3xa9servxc3xa9 au systxc3xa8me
/dev/sda2              296.3G  36% /media/ubuntu/74720B3B720B019A
/dev/sda3               86.3M  84% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sdb1               10.9G  27% /cdrom
/dev/sdd1                511M   0% /media/ubuntu/43E3-C49F
/dev/sdd5              485.8M  24% /media/ubuntu/e754ef8b-0783-4e95-9bbd-26b2fb0b9e25

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/mapper/crypt-root ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
/dev/sda1              fuseblk         rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda2              fuseblk         rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda3              fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdd1              vfat            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=999,gid=999,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdd5              ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
crypt-root
crypt-swap_1
crypt-swap_2
luks-36aadf0f-9ed5-4c9a-ab49-82490351ab49

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1

======================== sdd5/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================

### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sdd5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0,685546875 = 0,736100352    grub/grub.cfg                                  2
   0,638744354 = 0,685846528    grub/i386-pc/core.img                          1
   0,952426910 = 1,022660608    initrd.img-5.15.0-117-generic                  5
   0,865718842 = 0,929558528    initrd.img-linux-image-5.15.0-117-generic      5

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sdd6


================================= User choice ==================================

Is there RAID on this computer? no


==================== blkid (filtered) before lvm activation ====================

/dev/sda1: LABEL="RM-CM-)servM-CM-) au systM-CM-(me" UUID="3EFA09DDFA099277" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0f8b607c-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="74720B3B720B019A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0f8b607c-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="70AED1B4AED17358" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="0f8b607c-03"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="UBUNTU 20_0" UUID="849E-DC4E" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="4060af9a-01"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="43E3-C49F" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="3fb22b3d-01"
/dev/sdd5: UUID="e754ef8b-0783-4e95-9bbd-26b2fb0b9e25" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3fb22b3d-05"
/dev/sdd6: UUID="36aadf0f-9ed5-4c9a-ab49-82490351ab49" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="3fb22b3d-06"
/dev/mapper/luks-36aadf0f-9ed5-4c9a-ab49-82490351ab49: UUID="t3WzIL-7Lks-x25L-EAFS-FHAi-V0rt-PpOAEm" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/crypt-root: UUID="eb8d3fc1-635e-4612-93d5-3b551fee8d2c" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/crypt-swap_1: UUID="9d7ef9bf-8a9d-43bd-9de4-3b2adf69f6d2" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/crypt-swap_2: UUID="a396daf8-2604-4e5f-957a-1f01a7bbe4b2" TYPE="swap"


================================ LVM activation ================================

modprobe dm-mod  
vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "crypt" using metadata type lvm2
vgchange -ay
  3 logical volume(s) in volume group "crypt" now active
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/crypt/root' [<223.18 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/crypt/swap_1' [976.00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/crypt/swap_2' [4.00 GiB] inherit
blkid -g



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to enable-lvm) and reinstall the grub2 of
mapper/crypt-root into the MBR of sda,
using the following options:  sdd5/boot
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because legacy Windows detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix

Confirmation request before suggested repair: __________________________________

You may want to retry after mounting your encrypted partitions so that the tool can verify their contents. (cryptsetup open)
Are you sure you want to continue anyway?

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda (ATA Samsung SSD 870) disk!


I am confused. Is Boot-Repair report from A or B? Are both old BIOS systems? Generally any system so old (prior to 2012) to be BIOS/MBR does not really support Ubuntu and you need lighter weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)
I found even Kubuntu will work on older system, but it is more middle weight. what brand/model system.

Boot-repair is launched on the liveusb key (disk sdb) . LiveUSB key is launched on the computer A. The disk B (sdd) is also connected via usb to the A-computer.

You have to decrypt your install on sdd and then use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to choose sdd install, both /boot & / (root) in LVM encrypted partition and install boot loader to drive sdd. Is sdd BIOS/MBR?
